# Mips Assembly why is it not branching when my float is less then zero?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

So I have a value stored in `number: .word 0` and I convert that floating point and store it in $t1 but when I use bltz to ask if the value stored in $t1 is less then zero it never branches to the "Negative" function?

```
   s.s $f12, number
   
   la $t0, number
   ldc1 $f2,0($t0)  # Load double floating point number
   cvt.w.d $f2, $f2
   mfc1 $t1, $f2   # Take the integer in FP Reg and put into $t1
   
 
   bltz $t1, Negative
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing data types (single float and double), so I am confused (and perhaps the processor also).

`s.s` stores a floating point number into memory using a floating point representation, IEEE 754, *single precision, 4 bytes in size*.

You then load that from that same memory location as *double precision, 8 bytes in size* (which it isn't) into $f2 and tell the processor to convert this double to integer.  What value do you expect to get for loading an 8-byte value when you've only provided for and stored 4 bytes?

Have you tried looking at the values in the various (e.g. floating point) registers as you're doing this?

---

FYI, there are floating point comparisons that the processor can use for conditional branches, without converting floating point values to integer.

Comment: If I enter -100.00 the program should return "Nan".  I have a function for finding the square root and I pass it back and store it from $f22 to $f12.  Then I need a way of comparing that floating point value to $zero and decide if I need to branch to the "Negative" function.  I am adding the full code to the main file.  My second file "sqrt" just calculates the square root and passes it back in $f22.

Comment: For comparing against zero specifically, one might want to just `mfc1 $t0, $f22` / `bltz $t0, target` to branch on the sign-bit of the FP bit-pattern.  That would treat `-0.0f` as negative, and also `-NaN`, but otherwise should be equivalent.  Fewer instructions, but IDK about latency.  But if you need exact IEEE semantics for `f < 0.0f`, yeah use FP compares.  Converting to integer does handle `-0.0f`, treating it as not less than 0.0f, but IDK what MIPS fp->int conversion does for NaN or out-of-range integers (e.g. greater than INT_MAX)

Comment: Still quite confused on what I need to change here.  Assembly is confusing.... Luckily this is almost my last assignment in this class.

Comment: Never mind.  I just reviewed what you said again @PeterCordes I was able to get it working.  Thank you!  Slowly learning from these programs I do and what probably takes you guys 10 minutes takes me 10 hours lol.